# Simple post and get methods in Django

Tags: django, forms, post

I'm a newbie in Django and I have stupid question. I've seen a lot of tutorials, but I can't understand how to work with post data in Django. 
I have a form with 1 text field and 1 'choose' field, after that I press 'Submit' button and

Django displays me messages about certificates and other sh1...
So please give me example with forms, post data, and get data. 
Another question is - how to add information in database, from values that user input in forms. I can add static info, but it doesn't work for me.

I know that this should be simple, but I'm seems to be stupid.

It will helps many others I think.

Answer (score 3):

To add information into the db from forms, you should be using ModelForms. It's all very well documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Answer (score 2):

The data from a form that is posted to your view is available in `request.POST`. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/ for more info.

I would strongly suggest you work through the tutorial. It will answer all your questions and more. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/